# Follow link after scraping single page react site with Scrapy and Splash

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm currently using Scrapy to scrape a website. I'm also using Splash to render that website. The html returned by the response after going through splash is

```
<li data-link="shoppingSearch" class="menu-list-item__body--item" 
data-reactid=".0.1.1.0.1.$1.1.0.$0">Book</li>
```

I can create a selector to pull the data-link or the reactid, but I'm not sure how to follow this link. My end goal is to get a form and submit data to it.

Comment: There is a JS onClick handler attached to that node that does the navigation. You'd have to simulate an actual click on that node.

Comment: Thanks for the information, can that be done with scrapy? I'll look into it, that gives me a starting place.

Comment: Maybe you can just see what the URL it navigates to is and see where the dynamic data in that URL is coming from (probably some ID from a list received from some web api call). You could then mock the navigation action that way. Not a general purpose solution but probably the lowest possible level you can go.

Comment: Yah this turned into a pain and I took a different approach. I think it gets its URLs from a config.js file, which I now just read and follow. I didn't see any API calls for it. It's mobile.southwest.com I'm scraping. It's just for personal use, trying to log costs over time. It works now, I access their API directly after reading the config.js for some data I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing `wait` parameter if you are using splash's http api or call `splash:wait()` function if you run lua code.

e.g.:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=http://domain.com/page-with-javascript.html&wait=3'
```

See splash [render.html endpoint arguments](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait#render-html) and [splash:wait()](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait#render-html)

Comment: I must not fully understand, I'm pretty sure the page is fully loaded. I increased wait to 5 seconds and I still get the link as described above.